# Which AWS service use for repetitive task

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a question for my R&D

Let me explain my problem :

I have a script which call an API and take result of it. The problem is that API take 15seconds to respond, and i have to call this API a lot of time.

I work on AWS and i search a service which can call this API enough time as i want without a timeout error (i've think about API Gateway or Lambda, but they have a timeout).

I've think about AWS Batch, but maybe you have better suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use API Gate way and lambda as timeout period is 30 seconds.
2. you can also use lambda only, add your script into lambda function and call that API. Lambda function maximum running time is 15 minutes.
3. You can also use AWS BATCH but you need to create docker image from that script, so it will be extra overhead creating and maintaining docker images from simple task.

Better go with option 2.

Comment: That what i was saying, the API called take 15secondes to respond, and i have to call it maybe like 1000 or 5000 time, so API Gateway and Lambda while return me a timeout error

Comment: where is your api ?

Comment: It's an API to get commissions, it's not our API. It just take really long time to request a commission.

I've think about using AWS Fargate, do you think this service could help ?

Comment: You can use farget but to use farget you need to containerize your script/application code